# Not able to download the artifactory file directly from the jenkins url

Tags: jenkins, wget

Running this command:

```
wget "http://10.45.74.220:8080/job/OA4F-GA-BITBUCKET-REPO/35/appshellarchive-factory.json.gz"
```

Results in an error:

```
--2020-01-01 03:55:35--  http://10.45.74.220:8080/job/OA4F-GA-BITBUCKET-REPO/35/appshellarchive-factory.json.gz Connecting to 10.45.74.220:8080... connected. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found Location: http://10.45.74.220:8080/job/OA4F-GA-BITBUCKET-REPO/35/appshellarchive-factory.json.gz/ [following]
--2020-01-01 03:55:35--  http://10.45.74.220:8080/job/OA4F-GA-BITBUCKET-REPO/35/appshellarchive-factory.json.gz/ Reusing existing connection to 10.45.74.220:8080. HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 404 Not Found 2020-01-01 03:55:35 ERROR 404: Not Found.
```

Comment: Have you tried this url in a browser?

Comment: Note: Using the browser, i could able to download the file where as using wget cmd i get an above error.

Answer (score 0):

Try using curl command as below:

```
 curl -H "X-JFrog-Art-Api:$yourAPIToken" -X GET "$completepathoffile" -o 'file2.txt'
```